# Leaflet -> Removing CircleLayer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm trying to remove a circle layer from the map to draw a new one.

I have tried different solutions but none worked for me.

Maybe someone could find a way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin="">
</script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    #mapid {height: 480px; width: 480px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapid">
    </div>
    <p>Umkreis Km<select id="umkreis">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select></p>
    <script>
        var latitude = 0;
        var longitude = 0;
        // Creating the Map
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([53.079, 8.801], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data&copy;<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGVpY2tlciIsImEiOiJjazBveW9pcmQwZWV0M25vMHh4dnRkdmM3In0.JwNOtv10EsQrukcXe-Q2sQ'
        }).addTo(mymap);

        function onMapClick(e) {
            if (circles != undefined) {
                mymap.removeLayer(circles);
            }
            if (document.getElementById("umkreis").value == "--") {
                alert("nothing");
            }
            else {
                var fence = document.getElementById("umkreis").value * 100;
                alert(fence);
            }
            latitude = e.latlng.lat;
            longitude = e.latlng.lng;
            var circles = L.circle([latitude, longitude], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: fence
            }).addTo(mymap);
            //alert("Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat + " Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng);
        }
        mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried adding a Layergroup and add a circle to it and remove it with removeLayer() and clearLayers() like someone used it here in Stack Overflow to fix the same Problem.

Comment: You're using `var` twice, most probably re-declaring it in the context of the function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: OK thanks. I removed the first declaration at the beginning.  Still not working

Comment: Remove the other one instead :-) You need the variable to stay in scope between invocations of the click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited version of your fiddle which works now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title></title>    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin="">
</script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #mapid {height: 480px; width: 480px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapid">
    </div>
    <p>Umkreis Km<select id="umkreis">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select></p>
    <script>

        var latitude = 0;
        var longitude = 0;
        var circles;
        // Creating the Map
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([53.079, 8.801], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data&copy;<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGVpY2tlciIsImEiOiJjazBveW9pcmQwZWV0M25vMHh4dnRkdmM3In0.JwNOtv10EsQrukcXe-Q2sQ'
        }).addTo(mymap);

        function onMapClick(e) {

            //circles.remove();
            //if (mymap.hasLayer(circles)) {
            //    alert("yes");
            //}

            if (circles != undefined) {
                mymap.removeLayer(circles);
                mymap.clearLayers();
            }
            if (document.getElementById("umkreis").value == "--") {
                alert("nothing");
            }
            else {
                var fence = document.getElementById("umkreis").value * 100;
                alert(fence);
            }
            latitude = e.latlng.lat;
            longitude = e.latlng.lng;
             circles = L.circle([latitude, longitude], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: fence
            }).addTo(mymap);
            //alert("Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat + " Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng);
        }
        mymap.on('click', onMapClick);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Removing the circlelayer works now but the first should be removed an a new one should be drawn.

Comment: Ok, i found a solution. I had to remove the mymap.clearLayers() from the function besides your changes. Now the first circle will be removed and the new one will be drawn. Thank you @all

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables called `circle`. The first is defined outside `onMapClick` and is never initialized. The second, with the same name is defined and initialized inside `onMapClick` after checking whether the former has a value. You will just need to refactor `onMapClick`:

```
    function onMapClick(e) {
        if (circles != undefined) {
            mymap.removeLayer(circles);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("umkreis").value == "--") {
            alert("nothing");
        }
        else {
            var fence = document.getElementById("umkreis").value * 100;
            alert(fence);
        }
        latitude = e.latlng.lat;
        longitude = e.latlng.lng;
        circles = L.circle([latitude, longitude], {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: '#f03',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            radius: fence
        }).addTo(mymap);
        //alert("Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat + " Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng);
    }
```

Comment: @MashaE you are welcome. Did this fix the problem you face?

Comment: No it doesn't :(

Comment: @MashaE what happens if you click twice?

Comment: The first circle remains

Comment: @MashaE okay, so we have taken a step forward. What happens if you move the initialization of circles to the start of the function?

Comment: I tried, but when i want to add it (circles.addTo(mymap)) at the end it won't show up at all. Everything without any atempt to remove it.

Comment: @MashaE can you create a JSFiddle?